How do you solve for v_o in this clipper circuit?
Here is the circuit:

I tried to solve it, but I am just not sure if my solution is correct.
First I assumed that d2 is off for the positive half part of the cycle, then the circuit is simplified to this:
d1 is on when vo is larger than 2 (vd=0) so:
$$2=v_{i}\frac{2}{3}$$
$$v_{i}=3$$
From there, I applied nodal analysis to solve for vo when vi >3
$$ v_{i}-v_{o}=\frac{v_{o}}{2}+v_{o}-2$$
Is this the way to go, or am I far from the right answer?

Why not check your results with a simulator? Your handwriting isn't good enough btw.

@Andyaka I did, but I don't trust the simulator plus I want to see how it's solved. (Thanks for the comment about my handwriting I don't know how it helps)

Did you mean $d_1$ is on when $v_o > 2$?

@CosmicDust what result did you get from the simulator. I can't tell if you are writing a "K" or an "R" so yes, being neat in handwriting is very important particularly for this question. Please add the simulation results to your question.

@Andyaka here's the link to the simulation https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcAWaAOZYDMYEE4xIAmBAdgDZyIElSQFJ6BTAWjDACgB3cC8ItCCJFk4co0gcA5iGR5yQ5IzkKSCiRwBOQkSHKiwffVHDwOAeRBYijY1gx7RGnsNHGipIo6jcrN7x5expIAJjpuoq4g8kIgIUwAZgCGAK4ANgAuHABuvArGhgpgAiYQSlYSJjAIOeFijFHFgpXlXpXVWnVNdTGMhHCdAoJDig1ozabwA9rWfeJ+tk5CZtqB-MOe0eqTkrlr3fvzLYxYVVDQNWFrMWvucYmpmb6N84fOC-VCm2BHHAD2VjEJkwkFUElg8DwFAQ5BIpQ4QA

@SimonFitch Yes, edited, thanks for pointing that out.

What you have is essentially this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
All I've done is some re-drawing to finally get to the above-right.
The input voltage has a peak magnitude of \$30\:\text{V}\$ so the Thevenin of it has a peak magnitude of \$20\:\text{V}\$.
When \$-3\:\text{V}\le v_{\text{th}}\le +2\:\text{V}\$, then \$v_{\text{out}}=v_{\text{th}}\$ and just follows the input, as there is no current in either \$R_1\$ or \$R_2\$.
When \$v_{\text{th}}\le -3\:\text{V}\$, then \$v_{\text{out}}=-3\:\text{V}+\frac{1\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega+\frac23\:\text{k}\Omega}\cdot\left( v_{\text{th}}-\left(-3\:\text{V}\right)\right)=0.6\cdot v_{\text{th}}-1.2\:\text{V}\$. This \$v_{_\text{out}}\$ peak will be at \$-13.2\:\text{V}\$. There will be no current in \$R_1\$ since \$D_1\$ is off.
When \$v_{\text{th}}\ge +2\:\text{V}\$, then \$v_{\text{out}}=2\:\text{V}+\frac{1\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega+\frac23\:\text{k}\Omega}\cdot\left( v_{\text{th}}-2\:\text{V}\right)=0.6\cdot v_{\text{th}}+0.8\:\text{V}\$. This \$v_{_\text{out}}\$ peak will be at \$+12.8\:\text{V}\$. There will be no current in \$R_2\$ since \$D_2\$ is off.
(The above assumes ideal diodes with \$0\:\text{V}\$ voltage drop. You can work out the Thevenin resistance for each situation.)
